Proxy for custom control
I need a proxy server that can temporarily block an application  from accessing an endpoint, while allowing access to another service.
I have an monitoring app that backs up to a cloud provider. However when backing up, I need to block the app from receiving updates from the endpoint while using the network connection to access another cloud API to do the backup (that's the reason I can't disconnect the Internet connection to the app). Otherwise the incoming data won't be included in the backup.
Sure, its bad coding practice for a non-blocking app but I don't have access to the app source code so its beyond my control.
However, I can configure a proxy server in the application, so there is a chance.
Any proxy servers that do this?

I had the same issue, maybe this will help.
Achieve the selective blocking within a Kubernetes environment:
Fist, set Up a Kubernetes Cluster.
Ensure you have a Kubernetes cluster set up. You can use managed services like Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), Amazon EKS, Azure AKS, or set up a local cluster using Minikube.
Deploy your application in a Kubernetes pod.
Example:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-app-image:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

Kubernetes Network Policies allow you to control the communication between pods. You can define a network policy to block traffic to certain endpoints while allowing others.
Like this:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: block-specific-endpoint
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - namespaceSelector: {}
    - podSelector: {}
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 203.0.113.0/24 # Replace with the IP range you want to block
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80

You can use a sidecar proxy (e.g., Envoy, Istio) to manage and route traffic for your application. Deploy the proxy as a sidecar container in the same pod as your application. Like this:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-app-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: my-app-image:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
  - name: envoy
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.18.3
    ports:
    - containerPort: 10000
    volumeMounts:
    - name: config-volume
      mountPath: /etc/envoy
  volumes:
  - name: config-volume
    configMap:
      name: envoy-config

Then, create a ConfigMap for Envoy configuration to control the routing and blocking logic:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: envoy-config
  namespace: default
data:
  envoy.yaml: |
    static_resources:
      listeners:
      - address:
          socket_address:
            address: 0.0.0.0
            port_value: 10000
        filter_chains:
        - filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            config:
              stat_prefix: ingress_http
              route_config:
                name: local_route
                virtual_hosts:
                - name: backend
                  domains:
                  - "*"
                  routes:
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/"
                    route:
                      cluster: service_backend
                      timeout: 0.25s
                  - match:
                      prefix: "/blocked-endpoint"
                    direct_response:
                      status: 403
              http_filters:
              - name: envoy.filters.http.router
      clusters:
      - name: service_backend
        connect_timeout: 0.25s
        type: LOGICAL_DNS
        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
        load_assignment:
          cluster_name: service_backend
          endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: service-backend
                    port_value: 80

Finally, apply the network policy and deploy the sidecar proxy configuration to enforce selective blocking:
kubectl apply -f network-policy.yaml
kubectl apply -f pod-with-sidecar.yaml
kubectl apply -f configmap-envoy.yaml

It looks a bit intimidating, but it's not an overkill, it should serve you well to achieve selective blocking of specific endpoints while allowing other traffic. This approach provides a scalable and flexible solution for managing your application's network traffic within a Kubernetes environment.

if its an android ARM app does it work? Apologies am not up to date with latest  CD/CI paradigms, more of a traditional IT spec/dev

Apps that enable Proxy settings usually have a NO_PROXY directive, where you list endpoints where traffic shouldn't go through the proxy.
So you could in theory create a proxy that sinks traffic towards the endpoint you want to block via a null route or proxying to loopback, and let everything else pass via NO_PROXY directive.
